# Need some help finding this function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find a holomorphic function$f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\mapsto \mathbb{C}$ with $\Re{(f)}=\dfrac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$ and $f(1)=1$. I have gotten very stuck on this. Here is my working so far:

Given $f$ is holomorphic, the CR equations necessarily hold and we can write $f'(z)=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}-i\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$. [Using this formula for the derivative is suggested by the question].

Calculating;
$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \dfrac{-x^2-2xy+y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ and $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \dfrac{x^2-2xy-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$.

Hence, $f'(z) = \dfrac{-x^2-2xy+y^2-ix^2+2ixy+iy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Now I noticed that $-\bar z^2 = -x^2+2ixy+y^2$ and $-i\bar z^2 = -ix^2-2xy+iy^2$

Thus we can write $f'(z)=\dfrac{-\bar z^2 -i\bar z^2}{|z|^4} = (-1-i)\dfrac{\bar z^2}{|z|^4} = (-1-i)\dfrac{1}{z^2|z|^2}$

...and now I don't know what to do. I was hoping for a function that would have an easily found antiderivative, but I have no idea how to deal with the $|z|^2$.

Comment: Why don't you try to find $v(x,y)$? I think that will be helpful.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay I just put du/dx into wolfram and found that its integral would give a nice expression for v(x,y), but the reasons I would want to avoid that is that my integration is *awful* - and I don't want to spend too much time in the exam on that for the marks I'd get. Usually this sort of question has an easier function to do calculus with, but not in this case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have $$f'(z)=(-1-i)\frac {\bar z^2}{|z|^4}$$ at the end you have something which is like $\frac 1 {z^2}$, while the final expression in the same line is like $\frac 1{z^4}$.

In fact all you need to do is to notice that $|z^4|=z^2\bar z^2$ to get $$f'(z)=-(1+i)\frac 1{z^2}$$ which is probably the easy expression you were looking for.